# Configure meeting presenter programmatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've implemented a solution that automatically schedules teams meetings for classes at a university and I would like to configure the teacher as the only presenter for the meetings.

I'd like to know if the is a way (using Graph or any other API) to programmatically set the values for the [Teams Meeting Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2tR6.png) properties: "Who can bypass the lobby?" and "Who can present?".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are [two apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/choose-online-meeting-api) for creating online meeting in graph api. I prefer to use [Calendar.Event api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#create-and-enable-a-meeting-online) to create a meeting and modify the parameter to control the attendees.

The attendees added in the parameter will receive a meeting email and have an event in their Outlook Calendar. They will be metioned before the meeting, while others won't.

All attendees except the organizer all need to get the permission before they join the meeting room if the meeting option is not `'allow everyone bypass the lobby`'(like the screen shot you provided). And I tried to find an Api to modify this option but failed. **There is no graph api which can change teams meeting option.** I use Fiddler and caught the request that calling while changing the meeting option, but this request needs an access token from api like 'https://api.spaces.skype.com'. This api is not supported by azure ad.

You metioned 'configure the teacher as the only presenter', I assume that you want to make others can't speak so I think you want to learn about the [roles of the meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/roles-in-a-teams-meeting-c16fa7d0-1666-4dde-8686-0a0bfe16e019) and how to control the roles such as mute someone. I think [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) will help you.
[image]